# Bridged Networking Problem with VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running an Ubuntu Linux guest in VirtualBox on a Mac host running OS X EL Capitan 10.11, and the guest isn't connecting to the host's Wi-Fi.

It's set to bridged networking, using the regular en0 Wi-Fi (AirPort). And in the VM network settings, there are only two options, wired connection and modem connection, and both don't work whatsoever.

How can I get the Linux VM to access the Mac's Wi-Fi?

Here is my output from ifconfig -a on the mac host:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether a4:5e:60:c6:7f:3b 
inet6 fe80::a65e:60ff:fec6:7f3b%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
inet 192.168.0.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fd00:fc:8d08:5b72:a65e:60ff:fec6:7f3b prefixlen 64 autoconf 
inet6 fd00:fc:8d08:5b72:913c:a7d1:1ec:fd5d prefixlen 64 autoconf     temporary 
nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
media: autoselect
status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
ether 4a:00:00:ac:b4:00 
media: autoselect <full-duplex>
status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
ether 4a:00:00:ac:b4:01 
media: autoselect <full-duplex>
status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
ether 06:5e:60:c6:7f:3b 
media: autoselect
status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
ether 56:a7:d6:a9:67:46 
inet6 fe80::54a7:d6ff:fea9:6746%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
media: autoselect
status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
ether a6:5e:60:6c:cc:00 
Configuration:
    id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
    maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
    root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
media: <unknown type>
status: inactive
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu - Check this link. You might get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with me. One of the solutions is to change the mac address when setting up the internet. As I understand it, it conflicts with the mac address of previously installed virtual servers. Therefore, the modem cannot configure the virtual machine[image]